# Java 8 stream filter local variable

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

```
Obj1 x = null;
String key = null;
while(it.hasNext()){
   x = it.next();
   key = x.getKey();
   listObject.stream().filter(e -> e.getKey().equals(key)).findFirst().get();
}
```

This is complaining with the following message: "Local variable key must be final or effective final..." I understand the the lambda context is created at runtime and it needs variables that do not change.

How can I use the functional style to find the object in the list?
I want to avoid the old fashion way of iterating over the list with `while`.

Comment: What is the main goal of your code snippet? You don't seem to store the result of `listObject.stream().filter(e -> e.getKey().equals(key)).findFirst().get()` to any variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can simply move the variable declarations to within the loop, thus making them effectively final:

```
...
while(it.hasNext()){
   Obj1 x = it.next();
   String key = x.getKey();
   listObject.stream().filter(e -> e.getKey().equals(key)).findFirst().get();
}
```

JIT/etc makes declaring variables outside of a loop a non-issue, really.

Answer (score 4):

In this case you would just need to make key final. For instance, this should work:

```
while(it.hasNext()){
   Obj1 x = it.next();
   listObject.stream()
   .filter(e -> e.getKey().equals(x.getKey()))
   .findFirst().get();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I want to avoid the old fashion way to iterate over the list through a while

Here is a way to iterate without *explicit* `while` loop:

```
StreamSupport.stream(spliteratorUnknownSize(it, Spliterator.ORDERED), false)
             .map(...)
             ...
```